# Return row for GROUP BY CASE WHEN IS NULL THEN (...) ELSE (...) even if record does not exist

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's consider the following scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE Replicant (Name NVARCHAR(10),Gen INT);
INSERT INTO Replicant VALUES ('tymtam', 2), ('Roy', 6);

SELECT   
    CASE WHEN Gen < 10 THEN '<10' ELSE '>=10' END as 'Gen', 
    count(*) as 'Count' 
FROM Replicant
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Gen < 10 THEN '<10' ELSE '>=10' END;
```

The result is a single row:

```
Gen Count
<10 2
```

Can I up-sophisticate the query so that I get a zero for the ELSE case?

```
Gen  Count
<10  2
>=10 0
```

---

## Update 2

My discriminator is 'is null'

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN Gen IS NOT NULL THEN 'Known' ELSE 'Unknown' END as 'Gen', count(*) as 'Count' FROM Replicant
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Gen IS NOT NULL THEN 'Known' ELSE 'Unknown' END;
```

The result is

```
Gen     Count
Known   2
```

and I yearn for

```
Gen     Count
Known   2
Unknown 0
```

---

## Update 1

My context is that I have pairs of queries (metrics) for different generations of replicants:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Metrics] (...) SELECT
'Metric X for >=10' as 'Name',
COUNT(*) AS 'Count',
(80_char_expression) AS 'Sum',
(80_char_expression) AS 'Min',
(80_char_expression) AS 'Max', 
0 AS 'StandardDeviation'
FROM Replicant  
WHERE TimestampUtc > DATEADD(WEEK, -1, Current_Timestamp)
AND Gen >= 10

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Metrics] (...) SELECT
'Metric X for <10' as 'Name',
--7 lines repeated from the 1st query
AND Gen < 10
```

I would prefer to have a single select to insert two rows, even if there are no records.

Comment: this doable using join, and union, but it would be a challenge if without using those.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `UNOIN ALL` make a comparison table for your score then do `outer join`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.word,
       COUNT(Name) 'Count'
FROM
(
SELECT '<10' word,9 maxval,0 minval
UNION ALL
SELECT '>=10' word,2147483646 maxval,10 minval
) t1 LEFT JOIN Replicant on Gen BETWEEN t1.minval AND t1.maxval
GROUP BY t1.word
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4378b/4/0)**:

```
| word | Count |
|------|-------|
|  <10 |     2 |
| >=10 |     0 |
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. I want to avoid duplicating the `select` params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`:

```
SELECT v.Gen, COUNT(r.gen) as cnt
FROM (VALUES (NULL, 10, '<10'),
             (10, NULL, '>=10')
     ) v(lo, hi, gen) LEFT JOIN
     Replicant r
     ON (r.gen >= v.lo OR v.lo IS NULL) AND
        (r.gen < v.hi OR v.hi IS NULL)
GROUP BY v.gen;
```

You can also use conditional aggregation and unpivoting:

```
select v.*
from (select sum(case when r.gen < 10 then 1 else 0 end) as gen_1,
             sum(case when r.gen >= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as gen_2
      from replicant r
     ) r cross apply
     (values (gen_1, '<10'), (gen_2, '>=10')
     ) v(cnt, gen);
```

Comment: The 2nd query returns 4 rows.